# How do I update list of string?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a string and I want to create a list of strings with prefixes.
For example

```
def foo(val):
    return ['PREF' + str(i) + '_' + val for i in np.arange(5) + 1]

b = foo('abc')
```

I expect `b = ['PREF1_abc', 'PREF2_abc', 'PREF3_abc', 'PREF4_abc', 'PREF5_abc']`
but I receive the error

> *** NameError: name 'val' is not defined

Why '`val`' is not defined and how to create that list?

Comment: What is np? Numpy?  1.10.1-py35_0

Comment: looks OK for me. Can you show full traceback? But you can do this: 

`return ['PREF{i}_{val}'.format(i=i, val=val) for i in np.arange(1, 6)]`

Comment: Hmm. The problems appears in debug mode only.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YbbS86Jk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try;

```
>>> def foo(val):
        return ['PREF' + str(i + 1) + '_' + val for i in range(5)]
... ... 
>>> foo('abc')
['PREF1_abc', 'PREF2_abc', 'PREF3_abc', 'PREF4_abc', 'PREF5_abc']
>>>
```

Comment: this won't touch the error, if any error - also just use range(1, 6) .